# Feedback on new tag: Visual Testing

Tags: discussion, tags

I've been here for years now but I have finally added a tag. Consider me a newbie on this and critically review [Visual Testing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-testing) <sup>[About](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/visual-testing/info)</sup>

I've tagged it on [How to test UI frameworks](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/422773/131624) and will add it to other questions as I find them.

If I'm going about this wrong in anyway feel free to sit me down and give me a talking to.

Comment: Do you want really *any* kind of UI testing to be included under the term "Visual Testing"? I mean, any kind of testing (manual or automated) of UI applications, using the UI? Or is your focus with this term more on "visual inspection"?

Comment: @DocBrown: I had the same thought. My initial reaction was it focused more on the visual aspect, especially given the question that was tagged.

Comment: Ok, I searched a little bit through the site and placed the tag at 6 older questions where I think it could be a good fit. Please check if that's the category of questions you had in mind with the tag

Comment: ... and since you started with this tag, may I suggest you try to find more question where it fits to in your eyes? That would give us a better basis for evaluating the description.

Comment: @DocBrown I found [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264797/how-to-best-do-cross-browser-cross-platform-visual-css-regression-testing/264798#264798) that seems to fit. Thanks for the feedback and the tagging. Everything you and Greg are doing are great improvements in my eyes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Visual testing, also known as **user interface (UI) testing** in software development is how developers ensure that an application appears to the end-user as it was originally intended.

<del>From the description of the tag or feels like `ui-testing` is the more appropriate name, but that isn't what you are going for. I ended editing the description to include that visual testing is a form, of subset of, UI testing.</del>

At first I was a little confused about the mention of UI testing. The term "UI testing" conjures up a number of other related terms, in my opinion:

- Manual testing/verification
- A specialization of unit testing focused on testing user interface components
- A specialization of integration testing focused on user interface components

Basically testing a user interface, in general, at any level of the architecture.

Yesterday I thought I found an existing tag called "ui-testing", but I couldn't find it today. I ended up editing the visual-testing tag description this morning without knowing I could no longer find the "ui-testing" tag:

> Visual testing, **a form of user interface (UI) testing in software development,** is how developers ensure that an application appears to the end-user as it was originally intended. **This could involve manual verification using your eyes or programmatically interpreting images of application screens.**

I added emphasis to the parts I changed. I think this relates visual testing to UI testing without causing too much overlap. Hopefully people will realize that not all UI testing is visual testing, but that visual testing is a specialization of UI testing.

Honestly, now that I can no longer find the "ui-testing" tag on this site, I'm reconsidering my tag description edit.

I just feel that visual testing is more explicit and clear, but saying it is also known as "UI testing" makes it a little more ambiguous.

Comment: That's a good edit. Thanks for the polish. UI testing would involve input from the UI. Which I don't think should fall under this tag. I like how you make that clear.